# Delete a node and its child nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I want to remove a node from an XML file.

Here is what the XML file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Movie to be deleted</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    <Time>time</Time>
  </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

I want it to end up like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    <Time>time</Time>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    <Time>time</Time>
  </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

This is what I have so far. This only deletes the child nodes though. It doesn't delete the  node.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(movieListXML);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
{
    if (movie != null)
    {
        if (name == movie["Name"].InnerText)
        {
            if ((this checks the data to make sure it is the one to be deleted))
            {
                movie.RemoveAll();
                doc.Save(movieListXML);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`XmlNode.RemoveChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild.aspx):

```
node.RemoveChild(movie);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using LINQ. For instance doing something like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

var movie = xDoc.Descendants("Movie")
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("Name").Value == "Movie to be deleted");

if (movie != null) {
    movie.Remove();
}

xDoc.Save(xmlFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.